# When sharing to facebook the image does not load

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The problem is for the website https://ukupdates.co.uk for some reason I cannot get the images to work correctly with facebook.

When using the debug tool I get this showing in the warning...

Extraneous Property
Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:title'.

I have tried many different plugins to create the meta tags and none work so don't think that is the issue. In terms of plugins installed I have AMP, Autoptimize, Short pixel image optimizer ive tried de activating these but nothing seems to solve the problem.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fukupdates.co.uk%2Frare-full-moon-happening-on-friday-the-13th-for-the-first-time-in-20-years%2F

> Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named
>   'og:image:width'. Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not
>   allow properties named 'og:image:height'. Extraneous Property Objects
>   of this type do not allow properties named 'og:image:alt'. Extraneous
>   Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named
>   'og:description'. Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not
>   allow properties named 'og:type'. Extraneous Property Objects of this
>   type do not allow properties named 'og:title'. Extraneous Property
>   Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:url'.
>   Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named
>   'og:updated_time'. Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not
>   allow properties named 'article:tag'. Extraneous Property Objects of
>   this type do not allow properties named 'article:published_time'.
>   Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named
>   'article:modified_time'. Extraneous Property Objects of this type do
>   not allow properties named 'article:author'. Extraneous Property
>   Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'article:section'.
>   Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named
>   'twitter:card'. Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow
>   properties named 'twitter:title'. Extraneous Property Objects of this
>   type do not allow properties named 'twitter:description'. Extraneous
>   Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named
>   'twitter:image:width'. Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not
>   allow properties named 'twitter:image:height'. Extraneous Property
>   Objects of this type do not allow properties named
>   'twitter:image:alt'. Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not
>   allow properties named 'twitter:url'. Extraneous Property Objects of
>   this type do not allow properties named 'profile:first_name'.
>   Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named
>   'profile:last_name'. Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not
>   allow properties named 'profile:username'. Share App ID Missing The
>   'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID
>   so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the
>   app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share
>   dialog. og:image could not be downloaded or is too small og:image was
>   not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please
>   define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image
>   that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Faceboo... See More
>   Parser Mismatched Metadata The parser's result for this metadata did
>   not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data
>   being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a
>   property only expecting a... See More

Comment: The URL you are debugging there says `og:image` was https://ukupdates.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/cropped-73A6F22A-8566-4268-A368-0FB2ADECCF01.png, but I am getting a 404 when trying to request that URL in my browser … unless you have some special treatment for the Facebook scraper implemented, that one probably gets the same response then.

Comment: Yea I noticed that im not sure why it does not load the image at that address. The plugin shortpixel does change png images to jpg and this particular image then ends up at https://ukupdates.co.uk/cropped-d4dc93d8-16c7-44d1-9eae-042153254660-jpeg/ shortpixel also hosts some images on its own site.

Comment: `https://ukupdates.co.uk/cropped-d4dc93d8-16c7-44d1-9eae-042153254660-jpeg/` itself is not an image URL, that returns an HTML document. That document shows an image element with the (working) source `https://ukupdates.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/cropped-D4DC93D8-16C7-44D1-9EAE-042153254660.jpeg` though.

Comment: Ive also noticed the debug tool showing the image it has found is at https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/client/q_glossy,ret_img/https://ukupdates.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/cropped-73A6F22A-8566-4268-A368-0FB2ADECCF01-678x381.png  ......… However viewing the opengraph data the metatags created by the plugin 'OG' give facebook this information <meta property="og:image" content="https://ukupdates.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/cropped-73A6F22A-8566-4268-A368-0FB2ADECCF01.png" />

Comment: The scraper tries to analyze the actual page content, if it doesn’t find proper OG data in the first place - and that first image is prominently featured inside `<figure class="entry-thumbnail">`, so that’s likely where Facebook got that URL from. But I don’t think this overrides an explicitly specified og:image, even if the URL for the latter doesn’t work. Other images “found” in the page source only get considered, if no og:image was specified at all.

Comment: What would you suggest to try fixing the issue?

Comment: What plugin are you using to generate the OG meta data? That probably needs to be configured differently, to pick the thumbnail image from a different source than it currently tries to.

Comment: It's the 'OG' plugin currently.